# Translate embedded C function to PHP function

Tags: php, c, function, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to "translate" the following function written in C in PHP. The problem is, the results returned by the function written in PHP are different from those returned by the one in C.

I think the problem comes from integer overflows in PHP which is not able to treat variables as unsigned 32-bit integer.

I tried to AND-mask all operation with **0xFFFFFFFF** without success. Have you got other solutions that could work?

The C function:

```
void
decipher(const uint32_t num_rounds, uint32_t v[2], const uint32_t key[4])
{
    uint32_t idx;
    uint32_t v0 = v[0];
    uint32_t v1 = v[1];
    uint32_t delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    uint32_t sum = delta * num_rounds;

    for (idx = 0; idx < num_rounds; ++idx)
    {
        v1 -= (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + key[(sum >> 11) & 3]);
        sum -= delta;
        v0 -= (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + key[sum & 3]);
    }

    v[0] = v0;
    v[1] = v1;
}
```

The PHP function:

```
function decipher($num_rounds, &$v, $key)
{
    $v0 = $v[0];
    $v1 = $v[1];
    $delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    $sum = ($delta * $num_rounds) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for ($idx = 0; $idx < $num_rounds; ++$idx)
    {
        $v1 -= (((($v0 << 4) ^ ($v0 >> 5)) + $v0) ^ ($sum + $key[($sum >> 11) & 3])) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        $v1 &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
        $sum -= $delta;
        $sum &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
        $v0 -= ((($v1 << 4) ^ ($v1 >> 5) + $v1) ^ ($sum + $key[$sum & 3])) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        $v0 &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }

    $v[0] = $v0;
    $v[1] = $v1;
}
```

Thank you.

## SOLUTION:

I found a solution: the following code uses functions which allows to do shift operations and additions on unsigned 32-bit integers.

```
function decipher($num_rounds, &$v, $key)
{
    $v0 = $v[0];
    $v1 = $v[1];
    $delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    $sum = ($delta * $num_rounds) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for ($idx = 0; $idx < $num_rounds; ++$idx)
    {   
        $v1 = _add($v1, -(_add($v0 << 4 ^ _rshift($v0, 5), $v0) ^ _add($sum, $key[_rshift($sum, 11) & 3])));
        $sum = _add($sum, -$delta);
        $v0 = _add($v0, -(_add($v1 << 4 ^ _rshift($v1, 5), $v1) ^ _add($sum, $key[$sum & 3])));
    }

    $v[0] = $v0;
    $v[1] = $v1;
}

function _rshift($integer, $n)
{
    // convert to 32 bits
    if (0xffffffff < $integer || -0xffffffff > $integer)
    {
        $integer = fmod($integer, 0xffffffff + 1);
    }

    // convert to unsigned integer
    if (0x7fffffff < $integer) {
        $integer -= 0xffffffff + 1.0;
    }
    else if (-0x80000000 > $integer)
    {
        $integer += 0xffffffff + 1.0;
    }

    // do right shift
    if (0 > $integer)
    {
        // remove sign bit before shift
        $integer &= 0x7fffffff;
        // right shift
        $integer >>= $n;
        // set shifted sign bit
        $integer |= 1 << (31 - $n);
    }
    else
    {
        // use normal right shift
        $integer >>= $n;
    }

    return $integer;
}


function _add($i1, $i2)
{
    $result = 0.0;

    foreach (func_get_args() as $value)
    {
        // remove sign if necessary
        if (0.0 > $value)
        {
            $value -= 1.0 + 0xffffffff;
        }

        $result += $value;
    }

    // convert to 32 bits
    if (0xffffffff < $result || -0xffffffff > $result)
    {
        $result = fmod($result, 0xffffffff + 1);
    }

    // convert to signed integer
    if (0x7fffffff < $result)
    {
        $result -= 0xffffffff + 1.0;
    }
    else if (-0x80000000 > $result)
    {
        $result += 0xffffffff + 1.0;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: post your PHP code so far also

Comment: If it's a known cypher, it's possible that you can find it among PHP's [Cryptography extensions](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/refs.crypto.php)

Comment: Also you can run your C function from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do math with very large integers in PHP, your option is basically to use strings and the arbitrary precision library of your choice:

- [BC Match](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)
- [GMP](http://es2.php.net/gmp)

In this case, GMP is your only choice since the other library does not support bitwise operations.

Comment: All integers must be limited to 32-bit. What do you mean by "very large integers"?

Comment: "Very large" means "larger that it can fit". For instance, 2147483648. For details about what fits, see the `PHP_INT_MAX` and `PHP_INT_SIZE` constants.